# Contributions on Github are not appearing

Tags: git, github, repository

I have set up the global username and email id on my system which is same for Github account already. I have committed for a private repo couple of weeks ago on "master branch" and it's appearing on my calendar. Though after switching to a different branch and pushing my code, the contributions aren't updating on my calendar. What's the thing with it? I use both git bash and Windows Powershell.

Comment: Just checked, Powershell is also good with the username and email id stuff

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+count+contributions

Answer (score 1):

Github just counts the contribution to the master branch. This will also exclude any commit that is done of a forked repository, unless you merge them to the main repository.

[Link to Github doc](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.13/user/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile#commit-was-not-made-in-the-default-or-gh-pages-branch)

Comment: That's actually weird, thank you though!

Comment: Added a link to the doc too.